# Simulating Network flows in NetworkX

Tags: python-3.x, simulation, networkx

I am trying to simulate a network flow problem in NetworkX where each node is constrained by its capacity. I need to specify the demand rates and the capacity at every node (also ensure that the flows don't exceed the capacity). As of now, I have defined the flows as edge weights.

Is there a way to do this in NetworkX? If so, what modules, should I be using? It would be nice if I could visualize this network simulation. A simple code involving 4 or 5 nodes would help a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Start experimenting with NetworkX until you get to an actual coding question -- something you can show us test values and a minimal example and a specified desired output for. This is partly because SO is a coding help, not a design help, site, but mostly because you're likely to solve your own problem doing this.

Comment: I have experimented with NetworkX with large graphs, but I am stuck at this problem as it involves the simulation of a network. I can rephrase my question better, and post whatever I've worked on so far, if that helps

Comment: "Simulation of a network" is still more general than a coding problem -- do up a [Minimal, Verifiable, Complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that gets as close as you can to the first aspect of the simulation that you can't figure out.

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks a lot for your help. I shall post it by tonight. :)

Comment: Great attitude redwing.  A little to add: obviously our time is as valuable as yours.  The best way to respect that time is to provide a piece of code that we can copy and paste so that we run it and see the outcome you're getting.  Then tell us what outcome you want to have.  The more specific you can be the better.  Often by the time you've done this, you'll have learned a bit more about how the language works and you'll have solved the problem yourself.  If you haven't, then it's usually a specific thing that you need to learn and someone can easily provide the missing step.